# Import After Effects camera data to Blender

Tags: animation

At this time, there is no way I know of to track live footage in AE and then to export the camera data to Blender as a matter of routine.

But, there is an interesting cheat that works very well in many situations.  I present it here as I know many have asked and the answers are all over the place.

Open the footage in AE and do a normal 3D camera track.  Set up the ground plane, etc. to get the AE camera fully aligned.  AE is ready to go as soon and the tracking is setup to enable a good target layer to be locked down.  Then, make a small (100 X 100 px) solid and lock it on a solid AE track point.  Make several more of these spread near and far and use enough that no frame goes by without at least 8 widely distributed.

Render out the footage and import it to Blender.  Set up the Blender 3D camera track manually with track markers covering each of the little AE solids.  Run the Blender tracker and voila.  Blender 3D camera movement will follow the live action perfectly.

Comments are welcome.  Good luck.

Comment: Please present your answer in the answer box below instead of in the question box (you are allowed to answer your own questions)

Comment: @Dale Your can post a question and answer it yourself http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/